# descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to 'pygame.Surface' object

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a project using `pygame`, trying to make an online game. As part of the program I send a message to the server over a network class: `n.send("img/cards/card_test")`

Here I define the `send` Method:

```py
def send(self, data):
    try:
        self.client.send(str.encode(data))
        return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)
```

This produces the following error:

> ```
> descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to 'pygame.Surface' object
> ```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

[`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) is a method to encode a `str` into `bytes` according to an encoding  (`utf8` by default). `data` cannot be `str.encode`d if it is not a string itself.

It looks like you are trying to `send` a `pygame.Surface` object here, check your code for places where you call that `send` function and ensure the parameter is always a string.